# "Maximum stack size exceeded" when using "this.super" in Polymer hierarchies

Tags: javascript, inheritance, polymer

When we have element hierarchies that have overridden parent functions, we run into a "Maximum stack size exceeded" from time to time. Most recently, I noticed the error creep up in a situation like this:

```
<polymer-element name="element-a" noscript></polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="element-b" extends="element-a">
  <script>
    Polymer('element-b', {
      attached: function () { this.super(); }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="element-c" extends="element-b">
  <script>
    Polymer('element-c', {
      attached: function () {this.super();  }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

http://jsbin.com/guqeyome/2/edit

My thinking was that if element A doesn't have an "attached" function, the super call in element C will eventually call nothing. Instead, it calls element B's "attached" function, which spins up an infinite recursion situation. The solution is to have an empty "attached" function in element A.

Is this by design? Am I doing something wrong? Is it a bug?

Comment: I would say this is a bug. The same doesn't happy for `ready()` or other custom methods. Can you file a bug?

Comment: Done: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/476

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "answer" to this question:

- For now, make sure a super function exists whenever you elements call `super`.
- The problem is being fixed upstream via https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/476 .